# Sort mysql result. order by col1, group by col2

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with 2 columns 'id' and 'name'. id is regular autoincrement index, name is just varchar.

```
id  name
1  john
2  mary
3  pop
4  mary
5  john
6  michael
7  john
8  will
```

I would like to sort search results like this

```
8  will
7  john
5  john
1  john
6  michael
4  mary
2  mary
3  pop
```

Id's are DESC, but all duplicate names are grouped together. It's ok If ASC is easier to achieve. I can reverse result in PHP if necessary.

Regular ORDER BY name,id DESC first sorts all names, and then sorts id's. That's not what I want. I am not interested in alphabetical orders of names.

I want id in DESC order, grouped by duplicate names if any.

p.s. I apologize it this is a duplicate question.

Comment: In your result id's are **not** DESC

Comment: In SQL `ORDER BY` will sort result-lines by comparing them one by one. Since the position of `5 john` in your desired result is depending on the position of `7 john` this will not work. I fear there isn't a relational construct that will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo: You are correct. Id's are not literally in DECS order. But there is one global DECS order (8,7,6,4,3) and one group of local DECS orders (7,5,1) (4,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you will need a temporary table for this.

```
SELECT TableName.id, TableName.Name FROM TableName
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Name, max(id) as maxid FROM TableName GROUP BY Name
) as tmp on tmp.Name = TableName.Name
ORDER BY maxid DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: I put WHERE clause between INNER JOIN and ORDER BY. It works :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql there is a group by clause, see [select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), and search for group by on the page.

There are examples on the page

so try this...

```
SELECT id, name FROM TableName
group BY name;
```

As your ID is acting as your primary key you probably don't need to tell it to sort ascending, but you could add the

```
order by id
```

if you desire.

of course the group by clause enables the ASC and DESC clauses to be added also, so you should get them in alphabetical order if you desire.

Although, that said just using an

```
order by desc(name)
```

will likely give you a similar result, you'll need to test it on your dataset.

be aware that this could be a very expensive select, as it tries to sort everything out into your required ordering.
As such if you are expecting to use it as the base of other selects you may decide to create a temp table, that you can then select against directly, otherwise the grouping may be re-occurring each time you use the primary table.
This will probably be something you want to look into doing once your data set becomes fairly large though.
David